# Why does this Javascript code stop sliding right at left: -100%?

Tags: javascript

Why does this Javascript code stop sliding right at left: -100%?

function slideLeft(sellBody) {

```
   var slideLeft = document.getElementById("sellBody");
   var currentLeft = parseFloat(slideLeft.style.left);

   if(slideLeft.style.left<"0"){

       slideLeft.style.transition = "left 1.0s ease 0s";
       slideLeft.style.left = (currentLeft + 100) + "%";
}
```

}

function slideRight(sellBody) {

```
var slideRight = document.getElementById("sellBody");
var currentRight = parseFloat(slideRight.style.left);

if(slideRight.style.left>"-500%"){

    slideRight.style.transition = "left 1.0s ease 0s";
    slideRight.style.left = (currentRight - 100) + "%";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var slideLeft = document.getElementById("sellBody");
var currentLeft = parseFloat(slideLeft.style.left);

if(currentLeft < 0 ){

   slideLeft.style.transition = "left 1.0s ease 0s";
   slideLeft.style.left = (currentLeft + 100) + "%";
}
```

and

```
var slideRight = document.getElementById("sellBody");
var currentRight = parseFloat(slideRight.style.left);

if(currentRight > 500){

slideRight.style.transition = "left 1.0s ease 0s";
slideRight.style.left = (currentRight - 100) + "%";

}
```

You can't compare a string as a number: `if(slideLeft.style.left<"0")`